# iPhone xCode | Slide a UIView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

How can I make a transition from a UIView to other, like a slide from left or right ?

Comment: The sample is called ViewTransitions http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html), refer [ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html), [Scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023) and [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080). Read the developer documentation for [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html), you wouldn't have had to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];

//The new position for view1
[myview1 setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)];

//The new position for view2
[myview2 setFrame: CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 100)];

//The animation duration
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

[UIView setAnimationDelay: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks texmex5 yours should be the accepted answer. A google search on "uiview commitanimations" led me to http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial which has a sample project